# How to remove separator in between subclassed UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have subclassed UITableViewCell. This class is linked to the following xib, which is just a UITableViewCell with a label inside of it:

[image: xib file]

If you look closely at the bottom, you can see the divider there. How can I remove this? 
Here's what the cells look like in a table view:

[image: table view]

edit: My table view controller is a subclass of `PFQueryTableViewController` from the parse.com service. My apologies for neglecting to mention this.

edit2: I changed the colors of the separators to red and have discovered some very off behavior that might aid in figuring out why this isn't working. There seems to be some spacer on the far left of each divider:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `UITableView` property `separatorStyle`. Make sure the property is set to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make it from the xib :

1. Go to xib
2. select table
3. make separator None.

Comment: Where do I "select table"? I can't seem to find it

Comment: From Xib file just click on the UITableview Control.

Comment: go to xib ->click on your table ->select attribute Inspector (forth tab) -> make separator none there

Comment: I do not have a xib for the table view, just for the table view cells.

Answer (score 0):

Set table separator style to none from design or code

Answer (score 0):

It simple.. just Go to the Xib File where you have put the `UITableView` and right side in the attribute inspector you will find `Seperator Option`.. just select `None` in that

OR

You can do it manually with the code

```
 tableview.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

just write this in your viewDidLoad method and it will be done..

Comment: I have placed `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;` into my viewDidLoad method, however the separators are still there.

Comment: use it at the time of creation of cell, in method -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I forgot to mention, my table is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. I am using `PFQueryTableViewController` from the parse.com service. Might this be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't put any view like a single line from uitableviewcell?

Comment: oh..you should mention this first... first update your question

Comment: I have attempted his method as well, and it still refuses to work.

Comment: can you give the link of library you using for uitableview?

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html

I believe the problem remains in the xib, as the divider is visibly there in the UITableViewCell xib.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. When I had adjusted the height of the table view cell to 125 over the usual 44, i had adjusted the height of the view sitting inside of the table view cell, instead of the actual view cell.

Thanks for the help anyways to everyone who provided suggestions.